# OpenMDAO: extract final message

Tags: python, openmdao

I am writing this new post in the hope that you could help me:

I am solving some optimization problems with OpenMDAO and I would be interesting in saving the final message which is printed when the computations are finished

example:

[image: OpenMDAO screenshot]

Does someone know if it is possible to extract this message and save it into variable for recording purposes ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is if you wrap your `run_driver()` method call in a context manager and redirect the output stream. In the example below I am writing the output to a file and reading it back. Note, that depending on the printing settings of your optimizer this might capture the messages during iterations, too.

Alternatively you can use `prob.driver.result`, if you are using `ScipyOptimizeDriver`.

```
import sys

import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.test_suite.test_examples.test_betz_limit import ActuatorDisc

prob = om.Problem()
prob.model.add_subsystem('a_disk', ActuatorDisc(),
                         promotes_inputs=['a', 'Area', 'rho', 'Vu']);
# Define the driver and optimization problem
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('a', lower=0., upper=1.)

# negative one so we maximize the objective
prob.model.add_objective('a_disk.Cp', scaler=-1)
# Call setup and provide the initial guess
prob.setup()

prob.set_val('a', .5)
prob.set_val('Area', 10.0, units='m**2')
prob.set_val('rho', 1.225, units='kg/m**3')
prob.set_val('Vu', 10.0, units='m/s')

# run the optimization
with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
    stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = f
    prob.run_driver()
    sys.stdout = stdout

with open("log.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

print("This was the OpenMDAO message:")
print(content)


print("Result from the driver:")
print(prob.driver.result)
```

Output:

```
This was the OpenMDAO message:
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [-0.59259259]
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 5
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
Result from the driver:
     fun: array([-0.59259259])
     jac: array([0.00017557])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 5
    njev: 5
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.33335528])
```